# 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql

i try to create table workouts with two foreign key fields. But MySQL shows me error [1215] Cannot add foreign key constraint. I`ve checked that parent tables are created and both fields have the same type. What else can be wrong?

```
drop table if exists areas;
drop table if exists roles;
drop table if exists trainers;
drop table if exists users;
drop table if exists workouts;
drop table if exists user_roles;
drop table if exists trainers_areas;

CREATE TABLE areas(
  id INTEGER UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
  name VARCHAR(30)
);

CREATE TABLE roles(
  id INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  role VARCHAR(30)
);

create TABLE trainers(
  id INTEGER UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
  name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  birthday TIMESTAMP,
  sex CHAR(1)
);

create TABLE users(
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
  name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  email VARCHAR(20),
  password VARCHAR(20),
  registered TIMESTAMP DEFAULT now(),
  enabled BOOL DEFAULT TRUE
);

CREATE TABLE workouts(
  id INTEGER UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY  NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  area_id INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  trainer_id INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  date TIMESTAMP,
  completed BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (area_id) REFERENCES areas(id),
 CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (trainer_id) REFERENCES trainers(id)
);


CREATE TABLE users_roles(
  user_id INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  role_id INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users(id),
  FOREIGN KEY (role_id) REFERENCES roles(id)
);

CREATE TABLE trainers_areas(
  area_id INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  treiner_id INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (area_id) REFERENCES areas(id),
  FOREIGN KEY (treiner_id) REFERENCES trainers(id),
  UNIQUE (treiner_id, area_id)
);
```

Comment: check if all your table is empty

Comment: @Vinie yes, they`re all empty, because i drop them before creating

Comment: Duplicate Question http://stackoverflow.com/q/15534977/2772563

Comment: Why have you not set a primary key for users_roles and trainers_areas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

added ENGINE=INNODB after each block.

Comment: without fixing the sign issue, it didn't matter

Answer (score 1):

datatypes must match, and `SIGN` too. If you don't specify `UNSIGNED`, then it is signed.

Messing with `foreign_key_checks` as mentioned in another answer ranks up there with the last thing I would do. People often forget they did it, and guess where the questions show up: Stackoverflow.

The below will work:

Create testbed:

```
create schema Monday001a;
use Monday001a;
```

Script:

```
drop table if exists areas;
drop table if exists roles;
drop table if exists trainers;
drop table if exists users;
drop table if exists workouts;
drop table if exists user_roles;
drop table if exists trainers_areas;

CREATE TABLE areas(
  id INTEGER UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
  name VARCHAR(30)
);

CREATE TABLE roles(
  id INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  role VARCHAR(30)
);

create TABLE trainers(
  id INTEGER UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
  name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  birthday TIMESTAMP,
  sex CHAR(1)
);

create TABLE users(
  id INTEGER UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
  name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  email VARCHAR(20),
  password VARCHAR(20),
  registered TIMESTAMP DEFAULT now(),
  enabled BOOL DEFAULT TRUE
);

CREATE TABLE workouts(
  id INTEGER UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY  NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  area_id INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  trainer_id INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  date TIMESTAMP,
  completed BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (area_id) REFERENCES areas(id),
 CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (trainer_id) REFERENCES trainers(id)
);


CREATE TABLE users_roles(
  user_id INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  role_id INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users(id),
  FOREIGN KEY (role_id) REFERENCES roles(id)
);

CREATE TABLE trainers_areas(
  area_id INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  treiner_id INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (area_id) REFERENCES areas(id),
  FOREIGN KEY (treiner_id) REFERENCES trainers(id),
  UNIQUE (treiner_id, area_id)
);
```

Cleanup:

```
drop schema Monday001a;
```

From the MySQL Manual Page entitled [Using FOREIGN KEY Constraints](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html):

> Corresponding columns in the foreign key and the referenced key must
>   have similar data types. The size and sign of integer types must be
>   the same. The length of string types need not be the same. For
>   nonbinary (character) string columns, the character set and collation
>   must be the same.

Comment: works great here. Mysql workbench and mysql 5.6.24 . I don't publish stuff I don't test.

Comment: I added ENGINE=INNODB;after each block. Now it works.

Comment: I appreciate the feedback. Will incorporate that in the future and not make that assumption. What version of mysql are you on: `select @@version`

Answer (score 0):

To find the specific error run this:

```
SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS
```

And look in the `LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR` section.

The data type for the child column must match the parent column exactly. For example, since `medicalhistory.MedicalHistoryID` is an `INT`, `Patient.MedicalHistory` also needs to be an `INT`, not a `SMALLINT`.

Also, you should run the query `set foreign_key_checks=0` before running the DDL so you can create the tables in an arbitrary order rather than needing to create all parent tables before the relevant child tables.